Encompass LOS loan/field monitoring codebase recursive logging issue
I'm looking to create a form specific (even full loan file) change log and have this codebase setup which works great except for the fact that I can't get it to stop capturing the logs of the field that I'm sending the log data to. So anytime a change is made, it sends it to CX_MONITOR_LOG which is great except then it captures the change to CX_MONITOR_LOG and basically is stuck in a loop.
I tried adding error logs that don't capture anything, throwing this in chatgpt, rewriting it a few ways and have had no luck.
Imports EllieMae.Encompass.Forms
Imports EllieMae.Encompass.BusinessObjects.Loans
Imports EllieMae.Encompass.Automation

Public Class DemoForm
    Inherits Form

    Private Shared isLogging As Boolean = False
    Private Const ERROR_LOG_FIELD_ID As String = "CX_ERROR_LOG" ' Replace with your actual custom error log field ID
    Private Shared eventHandlerAttached As Boolean = False

    ' Constructor to attach the Load event handler
    Public Sub New()
        AddHandler Me.Load, AddressOf FormLoadHandler
    End Sub

    ' Method to handle the form load event
    Public Sub FormLoadHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        InitializeLogger()
    End Sub

    ' Method to initialize the field change logger
    Public Sub InitializeLogger()
        ' Ensure the FieldChangeHandler is only attached once
        If Not eventHandlerAttached Then
            AddHandler EllieMae.Encompass.Automation.EncompassApplication.CurrentLoan.FieldChange, AddressOf FieldChangeHandler
            eventHandlerAttached = True
        End If
    End Sub

    ' Event handler for field changes
    Private Sub FieldChangeHandler(sender As Object, e As FieldChangeEventArgs)
        ' Avoid logging changes to CX_MONITOR_LOG or ERROR_LOG_FIELD_ID to prevent recursion
        If e.FieldID = "CX_MONITOR_LOG" OrElse e.FieldID = ERROR_LOG_FIELD_ID Then
            Return
        End If

        ' Prevent recursive logging
        If isLogging Then
            Return
        End If

        isLogging = True

        Try
            ' Create a log entry
            Dim logEntry As String = String.Format("{0}: Field {1} changed to: {2}", DateTime.Now, e.FieldID, e.NewValue)

            ' Log the change to the custom error log field
            Dim errorLogField As Field = EllieMae.Encompass.Automation.EncompassApplication.CurrentLoan.Fields(ERROR_LOG_FIELD_ID)
            If errorLogField IsNot Nothing Then
                errorLogField.Value &= logEntry & vbCrLf
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Log the error to the custom error log field
            Dim errorLogField As Field = EllieMae.Encompass.Automation.EncompassApplication.CurrentLoan.Fields(ERROR_LOG_FIELD_ID)
            If errorLogField IsNot Nothing Then
                errorLogField.Value &= "Error during logging: " & ex.Message & vbCrLf
            End If
        Finally
            ' Ensure the flag is reset
            isLogging = False
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class




